# Something strange in the tag synonym neighborhood

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Someone was able to suggest [c++11] be a synonym of [c++0x] (first line in screenshot), even though the reverse was already suggested (last line in screenshot).  And, the reverse was able to be suggested in spite of much fewer questions for [c++11].

(I'm not saying either should be a synonym of the other; that's [ongoing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89770).)

[image: Suggested tag synonyms page screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Fine, added another check to ensure no reverse synonym is proposed or in place prior to allowing creation of a new one