# C++11 should not be a synonym of C++0x

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Please remove the [c++11] tag synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103634/please-remove-the-c11-tag-synonym)

There had been several [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91482/wreaking-havoc-with-tag-synonyms) [discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91493/tag-synonyms-and-revisitation-of-hierarchical-tags) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91476/tag-synonym-voting-rules) around the question [whether the `c++0x` tag should become a synonym of the `c++11` tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89770/should-the-c11-tag-be-synonymous-with-the-c0x-tag). The way I interpreted the results (and the discussions of the same topic in the [C++ chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)) it was mostly agreed upon to wait until C++11 is official. (I disagree with that, BTW, but that's irrelevant here.)

Now someone made the `c++11` tag a synonym of the `c++0x` tag. (Note: That's the opposite.) Of course, that's stupid, because 5 years from now nobody will be speaking about "C++0x" anymore. [It seems the C++ chat room opinions are pretty alike here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/764450#764450). (Not surprisingly. How many of you are still discussing "Longhorn"?) Also, [the "culprit" admitted that the effect intended was the exact opposite of what he proposed and people voted for](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/764513#764513).<sup>1</sup>

So, the synonyms as they are setup now are wrong, they should be the other way around, and I think many wanted to wait with setting up synonyms until C++ is officially released.
***Can we please revert this?***

---

<sup>1</sup> There's a real usability problem in this. It seems "synonyms" are usually assumed to be mutually interchangeable. However, here on SO they are directed. The discussions in the C++ chat room about that revealed that just about everyone who got in touch with the concept first [got confused](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/794068#794068) [about that](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/794095#794095).

Comment: What's changed since [this question was asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91476/tag-synonym-voting-rules)? Everyone's blaming the tag system, when the real problem seems to be strong disagreement between the expert users.

Comment: @Cody: Please read again. That synonym is considered an error by the user who proposed it. He did it accidentally, and I bet most, if not all, of those who voted for it also confused the direction this works now. This makes just as much sense (none) as making `vista` a synonym of `longhorn` on SU.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with sbi, the synonym should be removed.

Comment: I agree with sbi. This is silly.

Comment: Synonyms are directed only in the meaning of "A has more uses than B". The meaning of A and B are not different and the direction does not express a relation on their meaning, but only a relation on the use of the spellings. So SO synonyms are really the "usual" synonyms people know - they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: I DO think `c++11` should have become a synonym of `c++0x`.  Neither is more "official" than the other (the official name is "ISO/IEC 14882:2011"), and C++0x has much more widespread use.

Answer (score 6):

There is no C++11 *yet.*  Once there is, this should definitely be reverted, even [flipped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89770/should-the-c11-tag-be-synonymous-with-the-c0x-tag/92461#92461).

Until C++11 is officially standardized (expected some months hence), I'm fine with this synonym: I'm not particularly in favor of it, but I see it as causing the least confusion, for now, out of all the alternatives.

Comment: Why? Shouldn't the synonym association just be removed entirely until the standardization is complete?

Comment: @jalf: "I do *not* think that keeping the two tags separate serves any useful purpose," as [Jerry Coffin put it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89770/should-the-c11-tag-be-synonymous-with-the-c0x-tag/92573#92573). Or even "Trying to enforce some kind of separation [between [c++11] and [c++0x] tags] is only going to lead to confusion in the long term." Which you said on that same question. ;)

Comment: It's still stupid to make `c++11` a synonym of `c++0x`, because the latter was a temporary name that's going to vanish pretty soon. SO would be the last place on the whole Internet still using the obsolete name in its tags. Yes, it's not _absolutely_ sure that the next standard will become C++11, which is why I (grudgingly) agreed to defer making `c++0x` a synonym of `c++11`. But the other way around is just plain stupid, and it seems [the majority of the chat room agreed with that](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/764450#764450).

Comment: @sbi: [c++0x] is an established tag with over eleven hundred questions.  People may already be watching it, have it in tag sets/feeds, and are definitely used to using it.  There are only 31 uses of [c++11].  What is the value of changing the dominant tag prematurely?  Unless you beat me to it, I'll lead the charge to change tag synonyms *once the standard is published.*  Until then, what's the difference between using a synonym and not using the tag in favor of [c++0x]? (Answer: one is automated and the other causes confusion.)

Comment: The number of questions already asked in a tag is irrelevant here, because those questions won't be affected. That leaves that, when someone tries to tag something `c++11`, they'll end up with `c++0x`. Which is just plain wrong. As Jerry explained in a comment to [his own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89770/should-the-c11-tag-be-synonymous-with-the-c0x-tag/92573#92573), "C++11" is the right name for the next C++ standard, even if its official release would be delayed.

Answer (score 2):

It is less likely that anything in use from the current C++0x standard will change, because that would invalidate code and compilations that are already in place. So in a sense, there is a set of code that is necessarily C++11, even though it doesn't exist as a standard.

At the same time, there are topics that are C++0x, because the remaining parts of the standard not yet implemented could actually change, at which point someone looking at the question tagged as C++11 would conceivably downvote as it the question might become irrelevant. However, people viewing the C++0x have to assume that information can become irrelevant as the standard changes.

However, if in fact the standard completes, there would no longer be a C++0x as long as any "newer" in progress standard is named differently.

Questions about non-standardized material from C++0x is only relevant while C++0x is in development, and the tag should reflect the time-relative nature.

So in short, I believe neither should be a synonym for the above reasons.