# Why are the upvote points in the [C++0x] tag not unified with those of [C++11]?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, up-votes, top-users

I just wanted to check the top-users list for [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) and found that this tag was made synonymous with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), which indeed is a good thing. But unlike with [template](/questions/tagged/template) and [templates](/questions/tagged/templates) some time ago, this time the upvotes of the former tags were *not* merged into the upvotes points of the latter tag.

The result is that most people who constantly earlier answered questions during the period C++0x was standardized and who asked questions within [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) now lost all their points because of the merge.

Is it possible to merge our points up into [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)?

Answer (score 4):

Old questions aren't automatically affected by the synonym, only new ones will be.

For old reputation to be converted old `c++0x` questions need to get converted to `c++11` questions. This should certainly not happen en masse and automatically, as not all old `c++0x` questions are real `c++11` questions. (Just think of concepts.)

You have, however, rather a lot of rep, and are thus entitled to convert the tags yourself on questions you deem worthy to be converted. (I.e., convert those where you have the most rep, as this will get you atop the list.)

Comment: Huh. I was not aware that you can have a synonym which at the same time can be a separate tag. Does this mean every time someone edits an old question it gets moved to the new tag?

Comment: Then it was a mistake to make C++0x and C++11 synonymous. *If* they are synonymous, *then* the consequence is that we *can* convert all C++0x questions to C++11.

Comment: And I don't want to change only my own answered questions to C++11. I want to see in what position I am relative to others. IIRC, James, Howard and me were at the top of C++0x. I would have to change all questions that are about C++11 and C++0x to C++11 if at all. There are too many. I still need to sleep, eat and code -.-

Comment: @Johannes: No it was not a mistake. Now everyone who enters `c++0x` into the tag field will have that corrected to `c++11`. That's good. C++0x finally is no more, and there should be ___no new questions___ coming in, and if they are they are likely tagged so by mistake. However, that does not mean that all old C++0x questions are now C++11 questions. Many of them are, likely _most_ of them are, but not all. That's why they must not be converted automatically.

Comment: @sbi tag synonyms are *not* hierarchies. A tag synonym is bidirectional. Whenever you can say A, you must be able to say B *and vice versa*. Otherwise it's not a synonym.

Comment: I *do* agree with your thinking, but it does *not* fit the "synonym" model of SO.

Comment: @Johannes: I think you're wrong there. C++0x and C++11 are synonyms now- that doesn't mean they always were.

Comment: @DeadMG no they are not synonymous now. Tagging a question about C++0x concepts C++11 now is just as wrong as it was two years ago.

Comment: @Johannes: Unfortunately, "synonyms" on SO aren't symmetric. Making `c++0x` a synonym of `c++11` [is not the same as doing it the other way around](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93173/c11-should-not-be-a-synonym-of-c0x).

Comment: FWIW, I cannot retag my answers because currently there seems to exist no way to list all one's answers to C++0x. If you try to, you end up with a list of C++11 answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104956/searching-for-c0x-does-only-list-c11-entries-but-no-c0x-entries

Answer (score 0):

I think that if two tags are *synonyms* then by definition they are *interchangeable* (they mean the same thing) and thus upvotes should count for both tags.

Comment: You'd think that, but on SO synonyms don't work that way. On SO, synonyms are aliases that ___have a direction___. That makes it a huge difference whether you're making `A` a synonym of `B` or vice versa. (To me it seems "synonym" is simply a misnomer here.)

Comment: @sbi http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75631/some-confusing-synonyms-are-active and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59285/synonyms-mean-interchangeable-not-similar

Comment: @Johannes: I am not sure why your are throwing those links at me, but if you look at the answers to those questions you will see that many are using an arrow to depict mapping of tags, which seems to support my claim above.

Comment: @sbi nope. the arrow points to the master tag, which is the spelling that has the most uses. Therefor the arrow means that *the meaning of the tags is vice versa*. Not the spelling.

Comment: @Johannes: I disagree. Everybody was upset when someone accidentally setup `c++11` as a synonym of `c++0x`, rather than the other way around. I haven't heard much complaints since it's the other way around. So there _is_ a difference in which way you set it up.

Comment: @sbi I think you only read half of my comment. I did say that the arrow direction has a meaning. And one was right to be upset because C++11 will (most probably) become the more popular spelling. This however doesn't mean that the meaning of the tags of a "synonym"-relationship aren't synonymous. It only means that the popularity of their spellings are not. If you have any further doubt or question, I encourage you to set up a meta question about it.

Answer (score 0):

However, there are several "unidirectional" [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) currently,
that is, the one does not necessarily mean the other:

[.net-generics](/questions/tagged/.net-generics) --> [generics](/questions/tagged/generics)

[java-annotations](/questions/tagged/java-annotations) --> [annotations](/questions/tagged/annotations)

[apache-tiles](/questions/tagged/apache-tiles) --> [tiles](/questions/tagged/tiles)

[python-3.2](/questions/tagged/python-3.2) --> [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

Comment: reported and fixed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104523/wrong-tag-mapping-approved