# Searching for [C++0x] does only list [C++11] entries but no [C++0x] entries. 

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

If one tries to list all one's answer to [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) it only displays [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) entries. That's particularly bad for users that want to retag their answers from [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) from [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), as recommended to users as a work around for not being able to automatically do that transition.

---

Update: I did a little SQL query which lists all the answers to a given tag from a given user, ordered by upvotes. That should assist anyone migrating his answers from one tag to another.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114165/find-answers-of-a-user-tagged-by-a-specific-tag

Comment: Have a look at [previous discussions here about these two tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B0x), and whether they should be synonyms or not.