# Please remove the [c++11] tag synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Sometime ago there was [a bit of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89770/46642) [a mess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93173/46642) around the tag synonyms of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x). At the time there was some reluctance to accept the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) tag as the master tag, so everything remained as it was ([c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) being the master tag, and [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) a synonym). But now that the FDIS was [unanimously approved](http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/), I hope that any doubts about the "11" are gone.

Can we have the ability to tag questions as [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) back?

Comment: Shouldn't the tag synonym simply be inversed?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. Maybe. I'm thinking about questions tagged [c++0x] that are about things that are not in C++11. This could be confusing. But keeping both tags could also be confusing. I'm torn on this issue.

Comment: The vast majority of questions tagged C++0x do refer to C++11 features. People stopped asking about concepts (the proposed C++0x feature, that is) long ago. Questions which are dated are irrelevant and will fade into the background, so we shouldn't worry about them.

Comment: Actually, the history is even more complicated. The first plead on meta (that I am aware of) was to [make `c++0x` a synonym of `c++11`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89770/), but that (despite the idea being quite popular in the C++ chat room) was [shot down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91476/). Then Jerry went in to propose it anyway, and it got enough votes, but _[he accidentally did it the wrong way](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/764513#764513)_. [I tried to have that reversed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93173/), but with no success.

Comment: And I'm sure I forgot some interesting twists in that tale... (Note that I have voted to close [my old question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93173/) as a dupe of this, successful proposal. Please vote, too. There's no need to have two of these.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I went ahead and nuked the synonym. Clearly the confirmed name should be a master or at least a tag.

Comment: The synonym is not on the list anymore, but the redirection is still in place. Can I assume this is just a cache issue?

Comment: yeah, we may have to wait for the next build on that ...